# How to find all docs having array with objects with properties in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have collection:

```
{
 "_id": "1",
 "userId": "2",
 "userName": "A",
}
{
 "_id": "2",
 "userId": "3",
 "userName": "B",
}
{
 "_id": "4",
 "userId": "5",
 "userName": "C",
}
{
 "_id": "6",
 "userId": "7",
 "userName": "D",
}
```

I need to make some sort of request, something like so:

```
db.users.find([
 {
  "userId": "2",
  "userName": "A",
 },
 {
  "userId": "3",
  "userName": "B",
 },
 {
  "userId": "5",
  "userName": "C",
 }])
```

And I want do get:

```
{
 "_id": "1",
 "userId": "2",
 "userName": "A",
}
{
 "_id": "2",
 "userId": "3",
 "userName": "B",
}
{
 "_id": "4",
 "userId": "5",
 "userName": "C",
}
```

Sorry for that find request not so readable here. Stackoverflow thinks its so many code here and few words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    { userId: "2", userName: "A"  },
    { userId: "3", userName: "B" }
  ]
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pbytI2z3vuP)**